# Folder creation in android

Tags: android

I have a working code of folder creation from where I copy pasted the code to another module for folder creation.I just edited the if statement but my folder is not getting created in the second case.I'm sure there must be some silly mistake but its making me frustrated to find the culprit.Kindly assist me:

Case 1 : Working perfectly fine and folder getting created.

```
      //Create folder in the SD card
      File pictureFileDir = getDir();

      //Check for the existence of the Folder
      if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
          String error ="error";  
          Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return error ;
      }else{
          Log.d("Syncdata","BalleFiles Folder created");
      }
.
.
.

          private File getDir() {
    File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return new File(sdDir, "BalleFiles");
  }
```

---

case 2: Used the code from above snippet,but just modified the if condn

```
    File pictureFileDir = getDir();  

    if (pictureFileDir.exists()) { 
                   Log.d("SyncFiles","Folder created");   
    }else{
        Log.d("SyncFiles","Data file does not exist");
    }
.
.
.
    private File getDir() {
        File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return new File(sdDir, "DataFile");
    }
```

In case 2,may be the folder is getting created then deleted.I'm not sure,but on a whole folder not getting created.What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed the call to [`mkdirs()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) which is the one that actually creates the folders.

Comment: but isnt getDir supposed to do the folder creation ,when it says new File(sdDir, "DataFile");  ?

Comment: also when I use 'if(pictureFileDir.exists() && pictureFileDir.mkdirs())' it doesnt solve the prob either.

Comment: No, from the documentation "The actual file referenced by a File may or may not exist". A `File` represents a file object, but the actual file backing it up may not necessarily exist.

Comment: That `if` won't help you. If it doesn't exist, then you need to create it. so you want an OR there, not an AND. Remember that java short-circuits AND and OR operators.

Comment: changing to OR did help me.Thanks man.I thought new File(sdDir, "DataFile"); creates a file if one doesn't exist already.Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It creates the `File` object, but not the file in disk that the new `File` represents.